# PDF form fields within longtblr: Bad register code (65536)

Tags: latex3, l3regex, tabularray

The code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{aeb_pro}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize

\begin{longtblr}{Q[c,m]X[m,1]Q[c,m]X[m,3]Q[c,m]X[m,j,3]Q[c,m]}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7\\
\midrule
\TextField[height=0.8cm,width=0.8cm,value=1]{} & glass & \TextField[height=0.8cm,width=0.8cm,value={}]{} & water & \TextField[width=0.8cm,height=0.8cm,format={this.getField('Brutto6').textFont='Arial';this.getField('Brutto6').alignment='center'},calculate={if(this.getField('manualBrutto6').value == 'Yes') this.getField('Brutto6').readonly = false; if(this.getField('manualBrutto6').value == 'Off') { this.getField('Brutto6').readonly = true; var CalcVolumen=(0+this.getField('Netto6').value)/1000;event.value=CalcVolumen.toFixed(2);}},value=0]{}\CheckBox[height=0.2cm,width=0.2cm,bordersep=0,borderwidth=0,bordercolor=1 1 1,name=manualBrutto6,format={this.getField('manualBrutto6').display = display.noPrint;}]{} & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \raisebox{-0.4cm+1.5\abovesep}{\TextField[bordersep=0,borderwidth=0,bordercolor=1 1 1,calculatesortkey=a,name=Leer6,width=0.8cm,height=0.8cm,format={this.getField('Leer6').textFont='Arial';this.getField('Leer6').alignment='center'},value=]{}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

will compile fine. However, if the table row is used 70 times, compilation will end in error:

```
! Bad register code (65536).
\__regex_query_set_aux:nN ...__regex_curr_pos_int
                                                  {#1}\__kernel_intarray_gse...

l.87 \end
        {longtblr}
?
```

Compilation will work [up to and including 69 lines](https://pastebin.com/ect49vXU) - the 70th line will then result in a `bad register code` error. Background: I'm using Python to grab data from an Excel sheet and generate a .tex file containing the required lines of table content. This works up to a certain number of lines. After that, I'll end with the bad register code. The (apart from the column separators similar) code outside of the `longtblr` environment will work fine. I guess that some kind of counter overflows? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: tabularray uses l3regex, which in turn  uses toks registers to store tokens, and access them directly by number where the number is the position. luatex has only
65535 toks register. So regex will e.g. not be able to handle text longer
than 65535 character (if the match is at the end)  (where it breaks exactly naturally depends a lot on the actual implementation of tabularray)

Comment: Thank you. `pdflatex file.tex --extra-mem-bot=1000000000 --extra-mem-top=1000000000` will give `Bad register code (32768).`, register seems to be only half the size here. Is there any suggestion on how to overcome the limitation for luatex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer has commented, at this time `l3regex` can only handle short string. As a workaround, you may use some macros to store long cell text. This makes it possible to write much more table rows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{aeb_pro}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize

\def\TFA{\TextField[height=0.8cm,width=0.8cm,value=1]{}}
\def\TFB{\TextField[height=0.8cm,width=0.8cm,value={}]{}}
\def\TFC{\TextField[width=0.8cm,height=0.8cm,format={this.getField('Brutto6').textFont='Arial';this.getField('Brutto6').alignment='center'},calculate={if(this.getField('manualBrutto6').value == 'Yes') this.getField('Brutto6').readonly = false; if(this.getField('manualBrutto6').value == 'Off') { this.getField('Brutto6').readonly = true; var CalcVolumen=(0+this.getField('Netto6').value)/1000;event.value=CalcVolumen.toFixed(2);}},value=0]{}\CheckBox[height=0.2cm,width=0.2cm,bordersep=0,borderwidth=0,bordercolor=1 1 1,name=manualBrutto6,format={this.getField('manualBrutto6').display = display.noPrint;}]{}}
\def\TFD{\raisebox{-0.4cm+1.5\abovesep}{\TextField[bordersep=0,borderwidth=0,bordercolor=1 1 1,calculatesortkey=a,name=Leer6,width=0.8cm,height=0.8cm,format={this.getField('Leer6').textFont='Arial';this.getField('Leer6').alignment='center'},value=]{}}}

\begin{longtblr}{Q[c,m]X[m,1]Q[c,m]X[m,3]Q[c,m]X[m,j,3]Q[c,m]}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7\\
\midrule
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\TFA & glass & \TFB & water & \TFC & \textbf{UN 1234} Methylal, 3, II, (D/E) & \TFD \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```