# How to solve longtblr error: ! Bad register code (32768)

Tags: longtblr

I encountered the following error when describing a long table using `longtblr`.

```
! Bad register code (32768).
\__regex_query_set_aux:nN ...__regex_curr_pos_int 
                                                  {#1}\__kernel_intarray_gse...
l.258 \end
          {longtblr}
```

I find out this may be due to internal register overflow issues with tax, as there are too many contents in the table.
I tried deleting some content or remove \hypertarget (which also occupies internal registers) from table to eliminate the problem.

Is there any other way to solve this problem without modifying the longtblr code?
Thanks.

the longtblr code:

```
\documentclass[AutoFakeBold,hyperref, UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{tabularray} % clean tables
\usepackage{xcolor}     % colors
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtblr}
[
    caption=SOC IOMUX,
]
{% format
colspec={Q[c,wd=1cm] Q[c,wd=1cm] Q[c,wd=2.4cm] Q[c,wd=4.4cm]Q[c,wd=2.5cm]Q[c,wd=1.5cm]Q[c,wd=1cm]},
hlines,vlines,        % horizontal and vertical lines
cell{1}{1}={c=2}{},  % enlarege cell{1}{1} to 2 columns
cell{1}{3-7}={r=2}{}, % enlarge cells {1}{3-7} to 2 rows
row{1,2}={bg=gray, font=\bfseries},   % fisrt 2 rows with gray backgraound
rowhead=2,
}
% header:
Package& & PIN name & Digitial Func & Analog Func & Power & Speed \\ 
\rotatebox{90}{BGA\_289} & \rotatebox{90}{BGA\_196} &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
% content:
P3&-&\hypertarget{pin:PA00}{PA00}&\seqsplit{GPIO\_A\_00(ALT0)\newline UART3\_TXD(ALT2)\newline SPI0\_DAT3(ALT5)\newline I2S1\_TXD\_2(ALT8)\newline I2S2\_TXD\_0(ALT9)\newline CAM0\_D\_6(ALT22)}&-&VIO\_B00&normal\\ 
P2&-&\hypertarget{pin:PA01}{PA01}&\seqsplit{GPIO\_A\_01(ALT0)\newline UART1\_RXD(ALT2)\newline SPI0\_SCLK(ALT5)\newline CAN3\_RXD(ALT7)\newline I2S1\_TXD\_1(ALT8)\newline CAM0\_D\_8(ALT22)}&-&VIO\_B00&normal\\ 
\end{longtblr}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

there are more than 250 rows in table.

Comment: Your table content is too long but what can be done is not possible to say without knowing how a typical row looks like, and how man't rows there are. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625591/2388

Comment: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/305

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer

I add the longtblr code in previous post. 
The current table has over 250 rows, and there may be longer tables in the future.
Thanks

Comment: well you are hitting a hard barrier. You can try lualatex (but while it has more toks register, they are finite too), or shorten the content by storing the code into commands as suggested in my link, or use longtable instead.

Comment: you could try `\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_set_eq:NN\__tblr_insert_braces:N \use_none:n\ExplSyntaxOff`. If your tabular contains nested tabulars (or other environments using ``\\``)  you must then surround them with a brace pair.